# fetch API in react using useeffect() and disply data

Tags: rest

my code is

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
```

function StaticData() {
const[sampledata, setSampleData]= useState([]);

```
const handleClick =()=>{
  console.log("ywhywh fetch data");
  
  setSampleData([])
```

}

```
const fetchData= ()=>{
  fetch(  'https://api.data.gov.sg/v1/environment/4-day-weather-forecast' )
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
  }
  useEffect(()=>{
    fetchData()
  },[])


return (
    <div>
         <button  type ="button" onClick ={handleClick}> Fetch Traffic </button>
                <button  type ="button" onClick ={handleClick}> Fetch Weather </button>

                <ul>
         {/* display weather info from api here  */}
      </ul>
    </div>
)
```

}

export default StaticData

Comment: It would be better if you could explain what your question is. Your post doesn't ask anything. Its just code blocks

Comment: This is first time I am asking.   I am fetching  external API  which contains  a weather data. , I want to display  that information in my UI component. I am developing a React App and I do not  know how to do this. So my question is where will this fetched data render ? in this component or APP.js ?  I need help with exact javascript code .

Comment: My API data is too long to post here